# Clipping with GL_LINES in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, clipping

I would like to implement the Cohen-Sutherland Algorithm with dynamic clipping volume in 3D Space. (i.e. with 27 regions). Assume I have somthing like this:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex3f(x1, y1, z1);
glVertex3f(x2, y2, z2);
glEnd();
```

1. Is clipping automatically done as default? If yes, how can I deactivate it?
2. I couldn't find an implementation for Sutherland in 3D Space. Do you know where I can find it?

Principally any algorithm would be fine as long as it does 3D clipping.

Comment: Clipping is done in clip-space (i.e. after multiplying your vertex by the ModelViewProjection matrix and dividing by w) by the hardware. What do you want to do exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I totally don understand what you are trying to achieve. But here is the basic rundown, openGL will automatically clip lines **that are not visible**. How do you think it will render lines outside of your screen?

If you want to implement clipping of an arbitrary 3D space you will have to do the math yourself and compute the start and end points. That you can feed into openGL, which in term will not render bits that are not on screen.

Comment: Hi guys, this is a university project so I kind of have to do it. What I want to do is, look at every vertex before feeding it to glVertex3f() and check if it is in the viewport, i.e. the specified cuboid. So basically the idea is to check the intersection between the line with the lines of the cuboid in 3d space. But still, I have no idea how to implement an algorithm like that

Comment: [Any questions?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm)